# Node.js Easyrtc deploy fail on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, webrtc, easyrtc

easyRTC server works fine on localhost but when I deploy it on Heroku it cause build fail and gave this logs

```
   Node.js app detected

   Creating runtime environment

   NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
   NODE_ENV=production
   NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
   NODE_VERBOSE=false

   Installing binaries
   engines.node (package.json):  >=0.8
   engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

   Resolving node version >=0.8...
   Downloading and installing node 12.2.0...
   Using default npm version: 6.9.0

   Restoring cache
   - node_modules

   Installing dependencies
   Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)

   > phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.16 install /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt
   > node install.js

   PhantomJS not found on PATH
   Downloading https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs/releases/download/v2.1.1/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
   Saving to /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
   Receiving...

   Received 22866K total.
   Extracting tar contents (via spawned process)
   Removing /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom
   Copying extracted folder /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1557749855763/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64 -> /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom
   Writing location.js file
   Done. Phantomjs binary available at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs

   > circular-json@0.5.7 postinstall /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/circular-json
   > echo ''; echo "\x1B[1mCircularJSON\x1B[0m is in \x1B[4mmaintenance only\x1B[0m, \x1B[1mflatted\x1B[0m is its successor."; echo ''


   \x1B[1mCircularJSON\x1B[0m is in \x1B[4mmaintenance only\x1B[0m, \x1B[1mflatted\x1B[0m is its successor.

   added 556 packages from 901 contributors, removed 35 packages, updated 32 packages and audited 3356 packages in 22.421s
   found 15 vulnerabilities (3 low, 6 moderate, 6 high)
     run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

   Build
   Running build

   > easyrtc@1.1.1-beta build /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98
   > grunt build

   Running "requirejs:build_api" (requirejs) task
   >> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
   >> './bower_components/webrtc-adapter/release/adapter.js'
   >> In module tree:
   >>     easyrtc_app
   >>       easyrtc
   Warning: RequireJS failed. Used --force, continuing.
   [Error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './bower_components/webrtc-adapter/release/adapter.js'
   In module tree:
       easyrtc_app
         easyrtc

     at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:28332:19
     at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:3059:39
     at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:2999:25
     at Function.prim.nextTick (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:28083:9)
     at Object.errback (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:2998:26)
     at Object.callback (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:2984:23)
     at Object.then (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:3038:23)
     at build (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:28289:12)
     at runBuild (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:30302:17)
     at Object.execCb (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1946:33)
     at Module.check (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1133:51)
     at Module.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1389:34)
     at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:384:23
     at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1439:21
     at each (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:309:31)
     at Module.emit (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1438:17)
     at Module.check (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1188:30)
     at Module.enable (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1426:22)
     at Module.init (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1038:26)
     at Module.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1264:30)
     at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:384:23
     at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:2697:17
     at Object.execCb (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1946:33)
     at Module.check (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1133:51)
     at Module.enable (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1426:22)
     at Module.init (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1038:26)
     at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1710:36
     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:9)
   ] {
     originalError: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './bower_components/webrtc-adapter/release/adapter.js'
       at Object.openSync (fs.js:436:3)
       at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:336:35)
       at Object.readFile (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:3658:27)
       at Object.readFileAsync (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:3672:32)
       at Function.require._cacheReadAsync (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:28102:25)
       at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:27671:48
       at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:3041:37
       at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:2989:25
       at Function.prim.nextTick (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:28083:9)
```

```
npm ERR!           at Object.callback (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:2988:26)
 code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
           at Object.then (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:3038:23)
           at Object.start (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:3031:34)
           at Object.context.load (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:27655:32)
           at Module.load (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1084:29)
npm ERR! easyrtc@1.1.1-beta build: `grunt build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm            at Module.fetch (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1074:66)
ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the easyrtc@1.1.1-beta build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
           at Module.check (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1106:30)
           at Module.enable (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1426:22)
           at Object.enable (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1807:39)
           at Object.context.enable (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:27620:38)
           at Module.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1411:33)
           at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:384:23
           at each (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:309:31)
           at Module.enable (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1363:17)
           at Module.init (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1038:26)
           at Module.moduleProto.init (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:27807:36)
           at callGetModule (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1453:63)
           at Object.completeLoad (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1840:21)
           at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:27756:41
           at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:3041:37
           at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:2989:25
           at Function.prim.nextTick (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:28083:9)
           at Object.callback (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:2988:26)
           at Object.then (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:3038:23)
           at Object.context.load (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:27735:28)
           at Module.load (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1084:29)
           at Module.fetch (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1074:66)
           at Module.check (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1106:30)
           at Module.enable (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1426:22)
           at Object.enable (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1807:39)
           at Object.context.enable (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:27620:38)
           at Module.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1411:33)
           at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:384:23
           at each (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:309:31)
           at Module.enable (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1363:17)
           at Module.init (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1038:26)
           at Module.moduleProto.init (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:27807:36)
           at callGetModule (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1453:63)
           at Object.completeLoad (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1840:21)
           at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:27756:41
           at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:3041:37
           at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:2989:25
           at Function.prim.nextTick (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:28083:9)
           at Object.callback (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:2988:26)
           at Object.then (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:3038:23)
           at Object.context.load (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:27735:28)
           at Module.load (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1084:29)
           at Module.fetch (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1074:66)
           at Module.check (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1106:30)
           at Module.enable (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1426:22)
           at Object.enable (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1807:39)
           at Object.context.enable (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:27620:38)
           at Module.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1411:33)
           at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:384:23
           at each (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:309:31)
npm            at Module.enable (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1363:17)
ERR!           at Module.init (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1038:26)
           at Module.moduleProto.init (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:27807:36)
           at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1710:36
           at Object.context.nextTick (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:27544:21)
           at Object.localRequire [as require] (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1699:29)
           at requirejs (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:2047:24)
           at Function.build.traceDependencies (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:29756:9)
           at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:28518:38
           at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:3092:24
           at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:3041:37
           at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:2989:25
           at Function.prim.nextTick (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:28083:9)
           at Object.callback (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:2988:26)
           at Object.then (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:3038:23)
           at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:3091:29
           at each (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:2951:21)
           at Function.prim.serial (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:3090:9)
           at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:28525:29
           at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:3041:37
           at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:2989:25
           at Function.prim.nextTick (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:28083:9)
           at Object.callback (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:2988:26)
           at Object.then (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:3038:23)
           at Function.build._run (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:28507:12)
           at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:28288:26
           at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:3041:37
           at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:2989:25
 A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm           at Function.prim.nextTick (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:28083:9)
 ERR!           at Object.callback (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:2988:26)
           at Object.then (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:3038:23)
     /tmp/npmcache.XD0ZP/_logs/2019-05-13T12_17_41_710Z-debug.log
           at Object.start (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:3031:34)
           at build (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:28265:23)
           at runBuild (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:30302:17)
           at Object.execCb (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1946:33)
           at Module.check (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1133:51)
           at Module.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1389:34)
           at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:384:23
           at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1439:21
           at each (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:309:31)
           at Module.emit (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1438:17)
           at Module.check (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1188:30)
           at Module.enable (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1426:22)
           at Module.init (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1038:26)
           at Module.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1264:30)
           at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:384:23
           at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:2697:17
           at Object.execCb (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1946:33)
           at Module.check (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1133:51)
           at Module.enable (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1426:22)
           at Module.init (/tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1038:26)
           at /tmp/build_8f4fed8983ed393789cb313224c46f98/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1710:36
           at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:9)
         ] {
           errno: -2,
           syscall: 'open',
           code: 'ENOENT',
           path: './bower_components/webrtc-adapter/release/adapter.js',
           fileName: './bower_components/webrtc-adapter/release/adapter.js',
           moduleTree: [ 'easyrtc', 'easyrtc_app' ]
         }
       }
```

```
   Execution Time (2019-05-13 12:17:40 UTC-0)
   loading tasks        603ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 67%
   requirejs:build_api  294ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 33%
   Total 898ms

   Build failed

   We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

   Some possible problems:

   - Dangerous semver range (>) in engines.node
     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version

   Love,
   Heroku
```

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed

Comment: Same thing happenning to me too, have you find an answer to this?

Comment: I am facing the same issue!    before I give you a solution that is working on my Part can you tell! do you have WEBRTC based something configures on your NODEJS?

Comment: I'm using EasyRTC's examples to build up my own app. You can get them [here](https://github.com/open-easyrtc/open-easyrtc). I've only added a new html/js file in the demos/ file and that shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

It's failing because it cannot find the webRTC shim adapter component needed. Did you install it via Bower? If not, do so with `bower install webrtc-adapter`.

If you already did, do you have a `.gitignore` file that is excluding your `.bower_components` folder?

Comment: I had a line on `.gitignore` file excluding `bower_components\` folder, i removed it and then ran the code you gave, but still the problem continues.

Comment: @oividiosCaeremos I would check to ensure that you definitely removed it and that the file is present in that folder manually before running the build. Also check the permissions on that folder.

Comment: it looks like easy-rtc has this problem because they haven't been updating the code for a very long time. Anyone having this problem should use open-easyrtc (can be found on github) to develop their own app since it's newer and there's actually people you can ask stuff when you're having trouble.